# Origin and meaning of "damn straight"

Tags: meaning, etymology, history, offensive-language

The phrase "damn straight" is now used as a way to emphatically agree with a statement, but where does it come from, and what did it mean originally?

Comment: In Australian slang "are you straight?" Could also mean "are you sober?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=straight) reports that *straight* to mean "true, direct, honest" is from 1520s.

Comment: e.g. "Are you being straight with me?"

Comment: also:  "Do you have you facts straight?"

Comment: Let's not confuse it with "are you straight?"

Comment: Which "are you straight" are you referring to?  I can think of several...

Comment: "Are you straight (as in _heterosexual_)," or "Are you straight (as in _accurate_ or _honest_)?"  Because I would argue that the latter is the same definition as the one you're referring to.  (or at least close enough)

Comment: @advs89: I was referring to your first comment. Clearly, "are you straight?" can have several meanings; that is what I was playing on.

Comment: haha ok - I was worried I was going to have to take back my +1.

Answer (score 3):

The third entry in NOAD lists the meaning of **straight** as

> 3 not evasive; honest : *a straight answer* | *thank you for being straight with me*.

Note the first example: *a straight answer*. The comment "damn straight" emerges directly from this kind of construction. It is always used in response to a statement that the speaker strongly agrees with, and is an acknowledgement of the candor and frankness of the original statement.

But there's more. It also parallels a similar possible response: "Damn right" (meaning "You're damned right.") and means the same thing. These two are interchangeable and probably merged in meaning; one often hears "You're damn[ed] straight," completing the merge. So in this sense "straight" and "right" mean pretty much the same thing. The actual meanings of "straight" and "right" are less important than the emphatic note of strong agreement.

Comment: The emphatic note is due to "Damn[ed]" being a (mild) profanity.